# How to install django specific version?

Tags: django

how To install specific Django Version i am getting only latest django version and i want an older version for my project work and that specific version is required for my working enviornment

want to downlod Django older version

Answer (score 3):

You can install this by specifying the version with:

```
pip install Django==4.2
```

This will in this case install Django-4.2. You thus can specify a different one by change `4.2` to `3.0` for example.

> want to downlod Django older version

That being said, it is often not a good idea to work with old versions. Only `3.2`, `4.1` and `4.2` are currently maintained, and thus receive patches for security vulnerabilities. For more information, see the [*Supported versions* section of the documentation](https://www.djangoproject.com/download/#supported-versions).

Answer (score 0):

for specific version of Django:

```
pip install django==<version>
```